# Angular 7 - Datatables - Upload button

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I need to add the "upload" button on my table:

Here is my TS file with dtOption :

```
        ...
        order: [[3, 'desc']],
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        stateSave: true,
        buttons: [
            this.datatableServices.getButtons(),
            {
                text: '<i class="material-icons" title="Supprimer">delete</i>',
                className: 'btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-fab-mini',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    that.deleteSelection();
                }
            },
            {
                text: '<i class="material-icons" title="Modifier">edit</i>',
                className: 'btn btn-success btn-fab btn-fab-mini',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    that.editSelection();
                }
            },
            {
                text: '<i class="material-icons" title="Nouveau">add</i>',
                className: 'btn btn-warning btn-fab btn-fab-mini',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    that.selectedList = [];
                    that.launchModal(that.selectedList,1);
                }
            },
            {
                text: '<i class="material-icons" title="Importer">archive</i>',
                className: 'btn btn-info btn-fab btn-fab-mini',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    let fileSelector = $('<input #fileInput onchange="importInternes($event)" type="file" >');
                    fileSelector.click();
                }
            }
        ]
```

As you can see I have already set buttons and that work perfectly.

Problem is for the last, I get

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: importInternes is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):1)

But if I call "alert" function for example, instead of "importInternes", it works

How can I call my "importInternes" method ?

Answer (score 0):

found !

Here the solution:

```
{
   text: '<i class="material-icons" title="Importer">archive</i>',
   className: 'btn btn-info btn-fab btn-fab-mini',
   action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        let fileSelector = $('<input id="fileInput" type="file">');
         fileSelector.click();
         fileSelector.change(function(){
             if (fileSelector[0].files.length > 0) {
                that.importInternes(fileSelector[0].files[0].name);
             }
         });

     }
 }
```